# User form to print an array of sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone explain why I'm loosing the array when the for loop is placed in `UserForm_Initialize` sub. If I move `Unload me` below the `PrintOut` and replace it with `Me.Hide` the array is passed with no problems. Meanwhile `rpvSheet` is passed correctly even with `Unload Me` at the beginning as shown below.

```
''Declare variables
    Dim recapArr() As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rpvSheet as Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
''Print preview
    If CheckBox2 = True Then Worksheets(recapArr).PrintOut Copies:=TextBox1.Value, Preview:=True
    If CheckBox3 = True Then Worksheets(rpvSheet).PrintOut Copies:=TextBox1.Value, Preview:=True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
''Direct print
    If CheckBox2 = True Then Worksheets(recapArr).PrintOut Copies:=TextBox1.Value
    If CheckBox3 = True Then Worksheets(rpvSheet).PrintOut Copies:=TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
''Check for hidden sheets that will not print
    j = 0
    For i = 3 To 4
        If Sheets(i).Visible = True Then
            ReDim Preserve recapArr(j)
            recapArr(j) = Sheets(i).Index
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    If Sheet5.Visible = True Then rpvSheet = 5
    If Sheet6.Visible = True Then rpvSheet = 6
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that reference types get lost when a UserForm is unloaded. Why would you rely on variables in an object that is being closed? If you need the array, move `Unload Me` after the print jobs. Or declare the array variable in a module. `Me.Hide` doesn't close the UserForm. That's why the array persists.

Comment: Just as a side note: `Sheet5` and `Sheet6` are not declared. Write `Sheets("Sheet5")` resp. `Sheets("Sheet6")`.

Comment: Yeah, I need the array and will be easier just to move `Unload Me` after the print jobs. `Me.hide` will be also needed to hide the UserForm before the print preview. I have pretty complex UserForm with multiple cases that changes not only visibility, but also sheet names ... so I prefer to use the object `Sheet`.

Comment: @Stringeater `Sheet5` and `Sheet6` are the code names of two (work)sheets in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that reference types get lost when a UserForm is unloaded. Why would you rely on variables in an object that is being closed? If you need the array, move `Unload Me` after the print jobs. Or declare the array variable in a module. `Me.Hide` doesn't close the UserForm. That's why the array persists.